# Cast Dictionary parameter type to object

Tags: c#, .net

I have Dictionary<T, object> that packed to object.
For exmaple:

```
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                { "a", "test1" },
                { "b", "test2" },
            };

            object obj = dic;
```

In real code I have a method that takes Object obj, so I don't know real type.
Now I need to cast that object to Dictionary<object, object>
I write solution, but I don't like it, maybe someone can give me better vision of situation

```
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "a", "test1" },
            { "b", "test2" },
        };

        object obj = dic;

        var source = obj as IDictionary;

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<object, object>();

        foreach (var key in source.Keys)
        {
            dictionary[key] = source[key];
        }
```

Comment: Why use `object` at all, either as an item or as a variable type? A string *is* an object, a `Dictionary<TK,TV>` *is* an object. What is the actual problem you want to solve? What you described is the assumed solution

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in real code I have a method that takes object obj. So I don't really know what I get there it can be dictionary or matrix or something else. But at least I can check if object is a Dictionary

Comment: Post the *real* code then. You don't need casting to check whether an `object` is actually a dictionary, you need eg `is` or `GetType()`. Why not make your method generic though? Or use overloads so you *don't* need to check the type? Or both? You can have both `myMethod(int[] p1)` and `myMethod<T,K>(Dictionary<T,K> p1)` overloads in the same class

Comment: The question is how to cast Dictionary that packed to object to another Dictionary type. I gave right example

Comment: Not really - the dictionary isn't packed, it *is* an object. You can't cast between unrelated types, you have to create a new dictionary. And neither is necessary. Now, you *can* inspect generic types. Check [How to: Examine and Instantiate Generic Types with Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-examine-and-instantiate-generic-types-with-reflection). `typeof(Dictionary<,>)` is a valid expression

Comment: You don't need to go through the `obj` either. Simply iterate over `dic` and add the keys, values to `dictionary`. Or use LINQ's ToDictionary, eg `var dictionary=dic.ToDictionary(it=>(object)it.Key, it=>(object)it.Value);`. A dictionary is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>` which means you can use `foreach` or `LINQ` on it directly

Comment: You didn't get question, but I up u because u spent your time.
I don't know the type of obj - it's just a Object obj parameter in my method. So I should work with Object, but I know, that actual type of that object is dictionary, but don't know Dictionary generic parameters type

Comment: object obj = new Dictionary<string, object>() - how to cast that obj to new Dictionary<object, object>() - my question

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ToDictionary` function like this:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "a", "test1" },
            { "b", "test2" },
        };

var dictionary = dic.ToDictionary(e => (object) e.Key, e.Value);
```

Bear in mind that in terms of performance it's close to the same as your solution, it's just more elegant in appearance.

Comment: as I mentioned my dictionary packed to object - object obj = dic;
I can't call obj.ToDictionary

Comment: But your source is already IDictionary. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: in real code I have a method that takes object obj. So I don't really know what I get there it can be dictionary or matrix or something else. But at least I can check if object is a Dictionary

Comment: Not much simplification then. You need to use the as operator AND check for null result. Then use the above method on the source to cast it.

Comment: That should be `e => e.Value`.